# Recreate stack trace with line numbers from user bug-report in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, stack-trace

**First, the problem:**
I have several free projects, and as any software they contains bugs. Some fellow users when encounter bug send me a bug-reports with stack traces. In order to simplify finding fault place, I want to see line numbers in this stack traces. If application shipped without .pdb files, then all line information is lost, so currently all my projects deployed with .pdb files, and so generated stack traces has this numbers.
But! But I do not want to see this files in distribution and want to remove all .pdb. They confuse users, consume space in installer, etc.

**Delphi solution:**
Long time ago when I was a delphi programmer, I used the following technique: on exception my application walk on stack and collect addresses. Then, when I receive bug-report, I used a tool that reconstruct valid stack trace with function names and line numbers based on collected addresses and corresponding symbol files located on MY machine.

**Question:**
Is there any lib, or technique or whatever to do the same in .NET?

**Status Update:** Very interesting, that often asking a question is the best way to start your own investigation. For example I think about this problem for some time, but start looking for answer only several days ago.

Option 1: MiniDumps. After a lot googling I have found a way to create mini dump from code, and how to recreate stack from managed mini dump.

- Redistributable assembly to create mini dump form code - [clrdump](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/clrdump.html#redist)
- Blog post about using previous assembly - [Creating and analyzing minidumps in .NET production applications](http://voneinem-windbg.blogspot.com/2007/03/creating-and-analyzing-minidumps-in-net.html)

This solution however need to redistribute two additional assemblies (~1mb in size), and mini dumps takes some space, and it is uncomfortable for user to send them by email. So for my purposes, right now, it is unacceptable.

Option 2: Thanks to weiqure for clue. It is possible to extract managed IL offset for every stack frame. Now the problem is how to get line numbers from .pdb based on this offsets. And what I have found:

- [PDB File Internals](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=22685), just for information because:
- [ISymbolReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.symbolstore.isymbolreader.aspx) - managed interface to read program database files
- And finally a [tool to convert .pdb files to structured xml](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/08/25/pdb2xml.aspx) for easy xpath processing

Using this tool, it is possible to create xml files for every release build and put them into repositary. When exception occurs on user's machine, it is possible to create formatted error message with IL offsets. Then user send this message (very small) by mail. And finally, it is possible to create a simple tool that recreate resulting stack from formatted error message.

I only wondering why nobody else does not implement a tool like this? I don't believe that this is interesting for me only.

Comment: FYI: In Delphi this is easy now because there's madExcept that puts a stack trace and other useful informations into a report on (unhandled) exceptions.

Comment: Which option did you choose? I am looking for solution myself too.

Comment: I chose second option and write bunch of classes to replace internal exception dump. I also planning write an article about my solution with all information and sources.

Comment: Once you write the article please a comment with link to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the offset of the last MSIL instruction from the Exception using System.Diagnostics.StackTrace:

```
// Using System.Diagnostics
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try { ThrowError(); }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        StackTrace st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(e);
        string stackTrace = "";
        foreach (StackFrame frame in st.GetFrames())
        {
            stackTrace = "at " + frame.GetMethod().Module.Name + "." + 
                frame.GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name + "." 
                + frame.GetMethod().Name 
                + "  (IL offset: 0x" + frame.GetILOffset().ToString("x") + ")\n" + stackTrace;
        }
        Console.Write(stackTrace);
        Console.WriteLine("Message: " + e.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void ThrowError()
{
    DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime();
    myDateTime = new DateTime(2000, 5555555, 1); // won't work
    Console.WriteLine(myDateTime.ToString());
}
```

Output:

> at ConsoleApplicationN.exe.Program.Main  (IL offset: 0x7)
>   at ConsoleApplicationN.exe.Program.ThrowError  (IL offset: 0x1b)
>   at mscorlib.dll.DateTime..ctor  (IL offset: 0x9)
>   at mscorlib.dll.DateTime.DateToTicks  (IL offset: 0x61)
>   Message: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

You can then use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to interpret the offset:

```
.method private hidebysig static void ThrowError() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
        [0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime myDateTime)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldloca.s myDateTime
    L_0003: initobj [mscorlib]System.DateTime
    L_0009: ldloca.s myDateTime
    L_000b: ldc.i4 0x7d0
    L_0010: ldc.i4 0x54c563
    L_0015: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0016: call instance void [mscorlib]System.DateTime::.ctor(int32, int32, int32)
    L_001b: nop 
    L_001c: ldloca.s myDateTime
    L_001e: constrained [mscorlib]System.DateTime
    L_0024: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
    L_0029: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_002e: nop 
    L_002f: ret 
}
```

You know that the instruction before 0x1b threw the exception. It's easy to find the C# code for that:

```
 myDateTime = new DateTime(2000, 5555555, 1);
```

You could map the IL code to your C# code now, but I think the gain would be too little and the effort too big (though there might be a reflector plugin). You should be fine with the IL offset.

Comment: I like your idea, and upvoted your answer, but this is only draft idea. Maybe there exist some method, or information how to map this IL offset to corresponding .pdb file (because there is many assemblies in project, and every assembly have it own .pdb).

Comment: It would probably be best if you just asked another question about how to map IL code to the .pdb files or the C# code. Though, as I said, I am not sure if this will be easier than just doing it manually.

Comment: For Watch Window:
new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace($exception).GetFrames()[0].ILOffset

Comment: This answer is awesome. You don't have to distribute pdb files, you don't have to write some custom tool (unless you *need* to get the line numbers super frequently so that using reflector and just looking at the IL code manually), and it works for Silverlight too!

Comment: I have to amend my previous comment. Works great in silverlight for debug mode compiled assemblies, but not for release: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264543/il-offsets-missing-when-silverlight-assembly-is-compiled-in-release-mode

Answer (score 5):

You should use [Environment.FailFast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100.aspx), call FailFast in the [Application.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception(VS.95).aspx) and a dump file will be created for you.

From the MSDN:

> The FailFast method writes a log entry
>   to the Windows Application event log
>   using the message parameter, creates a
>   dump of your application, and then
>   terminates the current process.
>
> Use the FailFast method instead of the
>   Exit method to terminate your
>   application if the state of your
>   application is damaged beyond repair,
>   and executing your application's
>   try-finally blocks and finalizers will
>   corrupt program resources. The
>   FailFast method terminates the current
>   process and executes any
>   CriticalFinalizerObject objects, but
>   does not execute any active
>   try-finally blocks or finalizers.

You can write a simple app that will collect the log files and send them to you.

Now, opening the dump file is a bit tricky, Visual Studio cannot handle managed dump file (fixed in .NET 4.0) you can use [WinDBG](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx) but you need to use [SOS](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx).

Comment: No suitable for my needs:
1. Most of exceptions are recoverable, so app must show info (optionally send it to mail) and continue. This method will crush app on any unhandled exception.
2. This method require a lot of action from user to send exception information to me. Almost nobody will do that. You can expect from users that they can copy-past information from error dialog and send it by mail, no more.

Answer (score 2):

You may create an application minidump whenever there is a bug and use it for offline analysis. This does not require you to deploy pdbs on the client machine. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163833.aspx) link can serve as a good starting point for learning.

Comment: Interesting article, but it require more time for thinking reading. And in general it is mostly for debugging (not stack recreation), and also require a lot of actions from user.

Comment: I am not familiar with C# .Net, but in WIN32 C++ applications, minidumps are very effective for analyzing customer site issues. I guess something similar must also exist for C#.

Comment: Minidumps are very useful for Native C++ code. But I haven't found a way to recreate a .NET stack trace from a minidump file!

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely on the right track of needing PDB files to accurately get source and line information.   I would question any perceived issues with shipping PDB files as actually being a valid concern, but, assuming there is a valid reason, you can do this but it requires more effort on you part to create the appropriate software build environment.

**Microsoft Symbol Server** will index the debug symbols and store them for use at a later date when you have a crash dump, for instance, and need symbols available.  You can point either Visual Studio or Windbg at your own symbol server instance, just like [Microsoft's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx), and it will pull down the symbols required for the debugging that version of your application (assuming you indexed the symbols with symbol server before shipping).

Once you have the appropriate symbols for a build, you need to make sure that you have the appropriate source files that belong that build.

This is where **Microsoft Source Server** comes in. Just like where Symbol Server indexes *symbols*, source server will index *source* to make sure you have the appropriate version of the source code belonging to a software build.

Working versions of **Version Control**, **Symbol Server** and **Source Server** should be part of your software configuration management strategy.

There are third party tools, some commercial, that will provide you with an API to generate application snapshots, but as you already understand, you need a mechanism for getting those snapshots uploaded to your environment somehow.

John Robbins on [PDB Files](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx)

John Robbins on [Source Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163563.aspx)

Check out [WinDbg documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) on getting a Symbol Server up and running.